# Records for ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, logstash, logstash-grok

Please refer the file [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflowtest/All_Logs_Collection)

The file contains ssh logs for Amazon Linux , Centos and Ubuntu.

I want to write a grok pattern in logstash , which will parse the file and give me the expected results.

My question is : How to get all the possible entries in the log file for the specific OS , is there any document on this ?
So that it will help me while writing my grok pattern.

I want the following cases to be covered for all the available OS in my logstash grok.

- How the login was did whether it was did using key or username and password
- Login is successful or failed
- Sudo login is successful or failed
- bruteforce attack : Failed password for invalid user or possible break in attemps . Is there any other entries which represent the same.

I hope I am clear with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find a detailled explanation of the log format, maybe I'm wrong.

[Here](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/analyzing-linux-logs/) you have some example of logs and a little Grok example.
If you want more Grok pre-written filters you can also use [this site](http://www.alexlinux.com/logstash-ssh-login-example/).

Then, here are the logs I have for all your different cases. I changed my IPs to 0.0.0.0, erased my fingerprints and changed actual logins to `username`.

**Failed login :**

> May  7 10:18:42 hostname sshd[6734]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
>
> May  7 10:18:44 hostname sshd[6734]: Failed password for invalid user support from 76.123.128.215 port 54943 ssh2

**Brute-force attack :**

> May  7 10:18:46 hostname sshd[6734]: Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for invalid user support from 76.123.128.215 port 54943 ssh2 [preauth]
>
> May  7 10:18:46 hostname sshd[6734]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=c-76-123-128-215.hsd1.ms.comcast.net
>
> May  7 10:18:46 hostname sshd[6734]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3

**Public key login :**

> May 11 17:21:21 hostname sshd[1972]: Accepted publickey for username from 0.0.0.0 port 43901 ssh2: ED25519 key_fingerprint
>
> May 11 17:21:21 hostname sshd[1972]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)

**Sudo session :**

> May 11 17:21:24 hostname sudo:    username : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
>
> May 11 17:21:24 hostname sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by username(uid=0)

**Password login :**

> May 10 10:36:23 hostname sshd[30746]: Accepted password for username from 0.0.0.0 port 58985 ssh2
>
> May 10 10:36:23 hostname sshd[30746]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)

With those logs you should be able to write your filters and extract comprehensive data.